# Counting rows from beginning each time when procedure is executed

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, row

I have a procedure which is executed with a parameter `Year_Month`, for instance `202211`.

My procedure insert the data into table `[dbo].[W_TRESC_BI_PROBA]` in the way shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UQIR.png

What I would like to achieve is to get column ID without duplicated attributes.

If I execute procedure for `202211` and for `202212`, the column `ID` is counted from the beginning for each `Year_Month` independently; as a result I have 1249 rows with duplicated ID for each month.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1foF.png

So I am given 684 independent ID like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3JCJ.png

I would like to get ID from 1 to 1249. When I first time execute the procedure for `202211`, I get ID starting from 1 to 565 and when I execute for `202212`, I get results starting from 566 and ending for 1249.

Thank you for some suggestions.

Comment: Please update your question and add your simple data and queries as code not images

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let me explain in more clarify way. Each month I have to execute procedure which insert new data into table. I would like to number each row in this table. Problem is I execute procedure for new month it start counting rows for new data from 1 row as a result I have duplicated values for ID. For example: I have executed 202211 first time. To the table was inserted 565 rows. When I execute 202212 I will have 1249 rows, but problem is 202212 starts count rows from 1 not from 566 and my ID is duplicated with the same number. If I execute for 202301 ID 1, 2, 3 etc. will be counted 3 times.

Comment: Please don’t add information/clarification in comments. Edit your question so that it is the best version of your question possible and contains all the information someone would need in order to provide you with an answer

Comment: Can you not make your ID column auto-incrementing?  That would seem to be the most practical solution.  Otherwise, if you can't set the column to be auto-incrementing, you will need to determine the maximum ID value before you do an insert, and add that value to your "ROW_NUMBER()" column.  However, this is not necessarily ideal if there's a chance that multiple instances of "inserts" could be running at the same time - in that case, you'll still potentially get duplicated values

Comment: Craig thank you for your suggestion. This is what I wanted to achieve.